# How to copy all of the files from one directory to another in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I want to copy all of the files from a subdirectory into another directory without copying the original folder.  In a terminal I would just do this:

```
cp -r dir1/* dir2
```

and then dir2 will contain all of the files from dir1 without containing dir1 itself.  I am trying to replicate this in a bash script and I am getting an error.  Here is my bash code:

```
cp -r $pck_dir"/*" $TAR_DIR"/pck/"
```

I get this error:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘./mailman/lists/mailman/*’: No such file or directory
```

This is strange because I can verify that the directory in question exists.  I believe bash is complaining about the '*' but I am not sure why.  Can someone enlighten me as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `cp -r "$pck_dir"/* "$TAR_DIR"/pck/` -- voting to close as typo.

Comment: Any issue in using `{}` around variables `cp -r ${pck_dir}/* ${TAR_DIR}/pck/`

Comment: This is a clearly stated question with a clearly stated answer. I had the same problem and thanks to this question I don't any longer. The explanation for why this question was closed makes no sense.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Expanding on devnull's comment:

- Quotes of *any kind* around a wildcard, like `*`, will prevent the shell from expanding the wildcard.  Thus, you should only write `"/*"` if you want a slash followed by a literal star.
- An unquoted variable will be subject to word splitting.  So, if pck_dir had the value `my dir`, then `$pck_dir"/*"` would be expanded to two words `my` and `dir/*` and both words would be passed to `cp` as separate arguments.  Unless you want word splitting, shell variables should always be in double quotes.

Thus, to get what you want, use:

```
cp -r "$pck_dir"/* "$TAR_DIR/pck/"
```

Answer (score 4):

Use rsync command line instead.

rsync -auv dir1/ dir2/

will synchronize recursively all files from the folder dir1 into the folder dir2.

man rsync

to get more explanation to know how to use this comand line.